# Codeigniter pre_system hook with library and model support

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I want to load meta information for my web at the very begining of code execution. I.E, i will pull logo src, site name and meta keywords/description from database and set it to session to display when my page executes. I am trying to use codeigniter hooks to do this. but when I use pre_system hook, it doesnt load libraries and models.

I will be using same scenario to generate installer for my script (like wordpress or joomla), so I need a proper way to initialize my configurations before page execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the CI_controller using MY_Controller and load all data in its constructor:

```
class My_Class extends MY_Controller {

   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       //Load logo
       //Load site name
       //Load meta
   }
}
```

Comment: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in .....

Comment: You need to create a MY_Controller first in the core directory. Read more here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Now i need to extend every controller with MY_Controller rather than CI_Controller :(. Anyway, thanks dude.

Comment: You are correct. On the other hand it gives you much more flexibility.